# Rails_admin redirect to 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have set up rails_Admin gem for my app. I want to redirect to a 404 page if the user is not an admin. Here is the code below -

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
config.authorize_with do |controller|
unless user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?
  #redirect to 404 - I need the code for this!
  end
 end
end
```

How do I do it?

Comment: `render file: "public/404", status: 404, formats: [:html]` Should render the 404 page. I do not use **rails_admin** but I render these file's when I want to render custom error pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
```