# Redirect to 404 when rails app crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new in rails. I want to add redirection to "404 page" whenever my "app crashed" or "page not found" or in case of "exception".

If someone have good tutorials please share with me or provide some simple solution.

I read this [Rails_admin redirect to 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892782/rails-admin-redirect-to-404) but it did not solved my problem.

Comment: by default rails shows 500 page in production mode if your app fails and 400 when url not found. Note: `in production mode`

Comment: If you want to add custom error pages you can refer http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2012/01/rails-3-1-adding-custom-404-and-500-error-pages

Comment: thanks, i am trying this.

Answer (score 1):

I have this method in my `application_controller.rb`

```
def not_found
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

and then in any controller when I do a `find`:

```
@model = Model.find_by(id: params[:id]) or not_found
```

I'm using Rails 2 at the moment though so it might be slightly different for your version.

Comment: thanks for your response. I already read this answer but in that case, i have to define "or not found" in all my controllers. Is there any other way that, e.g I define rescue in my application controller and works on whole app.

Comment: I'm not sure, are you wanting to show a 404 for cosmetic reasons? e.g. you want people to think the page doesn't exist when there's actually been an error? One way might be to just use the same 404 page as your 500 page but if you want to actually send a 404 response then I'm not sure if there's a way to override the default 500 with a blanket rule.

Comment: You may want to change `find(params[:id])` to `find_by(id: params[:id])`. `find` always raises an exception if there is no record found, therefore your example would never reach the `or not_found` part.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails guide has a chapter about [exception handling](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue). You can use [`rescue_from`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue-from) to run a custom method, when an exception is raised. The following example is from that guide and should be added to your `application_controller`:

```
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

  private

  def record_not_found
    render plain: "404 Not Found", status: 404
  end
```

You may want to change the exception type to whatever exceptions you want to catch. I guess that you can also catch from every exception by:

```
   rescue_from StandardError, with: :record_not_found
```

Note: I would consider this a bad practise and would instead just design my `500` error page to look the same then my `404` page.

Comment: hi thanks for your response, this is really helpful to me.  I just want to confirm that, will this work in case of application timeout error ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly is timing out I guess. The application or the webserver or load balancer in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

For 404 i.e. page not found, we can redirect page to custom route.
For this you need create new route,

> match "*path", to: "handle_errors#page_not_found", via: :all

which will redirect to `page_not_found` action of `handle_errors` controller.
Obviously you need to create a new controller `handle_errors`

For any other exception occurred in app, you can handle it using some customer method in `application controller` as

> rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found_error_handler
>     rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, :with => :default_error_handler

as so on ...

with defination of methods as,

```
def default_error_handler(e)
   render 'handle_errors/page_404', :status => 404
end

def record_not_found_error_handler(e)
   render 'handle_errors/record_not_found'
end
```